# Поменять местами активности в backStack

Tags: android, backstack

Прочитал статьи про флаги в манифесте и при отправке интент, но не нашел ответа. Подскажите, есть ли возможность реализовать такое: Первая активность  перешла на вторую. Жму на кнопку Back, перехватываю ее и хочу чтобы текущая активность ушла в стек , а та что ниже вызвалась наверх.  Я понял что с помощью флагов можно вызвать новый экземпляр первой активности, но я хочу просто перевести первую активность выше.

Comment: Я решил попробовать Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP , но он почему то  OnCreate отрабатывает по новой.  Такое могло быть, если активность уже очищена, но я только вызвал новую активность и сразу хотел возвратиться к предыдущей с помощью этого флага

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оказалось такой флаг существует.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyClassA.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Активность будет поднята наверх (она не дублируется, внизу ее не останется). Если нажать Back то мы попадаем на активность , которая подняла наверх текущую и если на ней вызвать еще раз этот же самый интент приложение упадет с исключением, т.к. мы кнопкой Back удалили эту активность из стека.